# Twitter Streams Api returns 403

Tags: twitter, twitter-api-v2

I have been using the Twitter V2 Streams Api for an over 6 months now. 2 days ago, the Streams Api started returning a 403 against my requests. Here is the response:

```
{
    "client_id": "--------",
    "detail": "When authenticating requests to the Twitter API v2 endpoints, you must use keys and tokens from a Twitter developer App that is attached to a Project. You can create a project via the developer portal.",
    "registration_url": "https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/projects/overview",
    "title": "Client Forbidden",
    "required_enrollment": "Appropriate Level of API Access",
    "reason": "client-not-enrolled",
    "type": "https://api.twitter.com/2/problems/client-forbidden"
}
```

I am on the free tier of Twitter API. According to the documentation, I should be allowed to pull tweets upto a 1500 tweets per month - and it seems I am well below that limit.

[image]

The Monthly Tweet Cap Usage says - "Certain endpoints (like filtered stream and recent search) have a limit on how many Tweets they can pull per month" - which is 1500.

I don't know what is exactly going wrong. The error clearly says that `"reason": "client-not-enrolled"` - which is not true - I am enrolled with Twitter Developers. And it also says `"required_enrollment": "Appropriate Level of API Access"` - does that mean I already have the correct API access level? (according to their docs, I do). So what gives?

Answer (score 0):

According to new API tier policy you cannot pull any tweets in Free tier, only manage tweets and users lookup are possible. I don't know why your developer dashboard is showing you 1500 pulled tweets.

In free version you can post 1500 tweets in a month not pull them at all.

Visit `developer.twitter.com/en/portal/products` to find out which API endpoints are available to which tier.

PS The documentation is still being updated.